# Metal Prevented Device Address Mode

Tags: c++, objective-c, gpu, metal

I am creating a graphics application that uses Metal to render everything. When I did a frame debug under pipeline statistics for all of my draw calls there is a !! priority alert titled "Prevented Device Address Mode Load" with the details:

```
Indexing using unsigned int for offset prevents addressing calculation in device. To prevent this extra ALU operation use int for offset.
```

So for my simplest draw call that involves this here is what is going on. There is a large amount of vertex data followed by an index buffer. The index buffer is created and filled at the start and is then constant from then on. The vertex data is constantly all changing.

I have the following types:

```
struct Vertex {
    float3 data;
};
typedef int32_t indexType;
```

Then the following draw call

```
[encoder drawIndexedPrimitives:MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangle indexCount:/*int here*/ indexType:MTLIndexTypeUInt32 indexBuffer:indexBuffer indexBufferOffset:0];
```

Which goes to the following vertex function

```
vertex VertexOutTC vertex_fun(constant Vertex * vertexBuffer [[ buffer(0) ]],
                                indexType vid [[ vertex_id ]],
                                 constant matrix_float3x3* matrix [[buffer(1)]]) {

    const float2 coords[] = {float2(-1, -1), float2(-1, 1), float2(1, -1), float2(1, 1)};
    CircleVertex vert = vertexBuffer[vid];
    VertexOutTC out;
    out.position = float4((*matrix * float3(vert.data.x, vert.data.y, 1.0)).xy, ((float)((int)vid/4))/10000.0, 1.0);
    out.color = HSVtoRGB(vert.data.z, 1.0, 1.0);
    out.tc = coords[vid % 4];
    return out;
}
```

I am very confused what exactly I am doing wrong here. The error would seem to suggest I shouldnt use an unsigned type for the offset which I am guessing is the index buffer.

The thing is is ultimately for the index buffer there is only `MTLIndexTypeUInt32`  and `MTLIndexTypeUInt16` both of which are unsigned. Furthermore if I try to use a raw `int` as the type the shader wont compile. What is going on here?

Comment: Show the shader code, especially how `vertexBuffer` is used, and indexed into. I believe it's referring to type of the expression used to index into the that buffer. Also, couldn't hurt to declare `vertexBuffer` as `const` (not the same as the `constant` address space). In what sense is the "vertex data *followed* by an index buffer"? Are they in the same buffer object?

Comment: @KenThomases I have updated my question with that code. Also is there a difference between const device and constant device? All of  the data passed in is not modified by the shader and they are on memory shared between CPU and GPU. The only one that changes frame each draw call is the VertexBuffer.

Comment: `device` and `constant` both specify an address space and are thus mutually exclusive. You can't do `constant device`. `const` tells the compiler the code won't be modifying a value. It can usually deduce that from what the code actually does, but sometimes specifying it makes things clearer. It's implicit for the `constant` address space. I was suggesting you use `device const Vertex *` for `vertexBuffer`, not `constant Vertex *`. I'd also suggest that you change `matrix` from a pointer to a reference, since it's not an array.

Comment: As to the error, I wonder if it's described backward. According to the Metal Shading Language spec, the data type for `[[ vertex_id ]]` should be `ushort` or `uint`, which are both unsigned. Have you tried an unsigned type for `indexType`?

Comment: I'm seeing this warning as well, with unsigned index type in the context of a trivial compute kernel; indeed, signed types give a compile error.  I wonder if it could simply be an Xcode bug?  This SO question is the most relevant google search result I can see.

Answer (score 0):

In Table 5.1 of the Metal Shading Language Specification, they list the "Corresponding Data Type" for `vertex_id` as `ushort` or `uint`.  (There are similar tables in that document for all the rest of the types, my examples will use `thread_position_in_grid` which is the same).

Meanwhile, the hardware prefers signed types for addressing.  So if you do

```cpp
kernel void test(uint position [[thread_position_in_grid]], device float *test) {
    test[position] = position;
    test[position + 1] = position;
    test[position + 2] = position;
}
```

we are indexing `test` by an unsigned integer.  Debugging this shader we can see that it involves 23 instructions, and has the "Prevented Device Mode Store" warning:

[image: warning]

If we convert to `int` instead, this uses only 18 instructions:

```
kernel void test(uint position [[thread_position_in_grid]], device float *test) {
    test[(int)position] = position;
    test[(int)position + 1] = position;
    test[(int)position + 2] = position;
}
```

However, not all `uint` can fit into `int`, so this optimization only works for half the range of uint.  Still, that's many usecases.

What about `ushort`?  Well,

```cpp
kernel void test(ushort position [[thread_position_in_grid]], device float *test) {
    test[position] = position;
    test[position + 1] = position;
    test[position + 2] = position;
}
```

This version is only 17 instructions.  We are also "warned" about using unsigned indexing here, even though it is faster than the signed versions above.  This suggests to me the warning is not especially well-designed and requires significant interpretation.

```
kernel void test(ushort position [[thread_position_in_grid]], device float *test) {
    short p = position;
    test[p] = position;
    test[p + 1] = position;
    test[p + 2] = position;
}
```

This is the signed version of short, and fixes the warning, but is *also* 17 instructions.  So it makes Xcode happier, but I'm not sure it's actually better.

Finally, here's the case I was in.  My `position` ranges above `signed short`, but below `unsigned short`.  Does it make sense to promote `short` to `int` for the indexing?

```
kernel void test(ushort position [[thread_position_in_grid]], device float *test) {
    int p = position;
    test[p] = position;
    test[p + 1] = position;
    test[p + 2] = position;
}
```

This is *also* 17 instructions, *and* generates the device store warning.  I believe the compiler proves `ushort` fits into `int`, and ignores the conversion.  This "unsigned" arithmetic then produces a warning telling me to use int, *even though that's exactly what I did*.

In summary, these warnings are a bit naive, and should really be confirmed or refuted through on-device testing.